# Python Zeep Client request throws error in xml exception

Tags: python, xml, api, zeep

When I run the following code, I keep getting the following error: `here is an error in XML document (113, 25). ---> The string '' is not a valid Boolean value.` I do not understand why this is happening. [Here](http://resumeparsing.com/#ParseResume) is the documentation and according to it the boolean fields are not required.

```
from zeep import Client

client = Client('http://services.resumeparsing.com/ResumeService.asmx?wsdl')
response = client.service.ParseResume(request={'AccountId': 'XXXXXXX',\
    'ServiceKey':'XXXXXXXXX',\
    'FileBytes': file_bytes, 'FileText': file_text, \
    })
print(response)
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Author of zeep here; which version are you using? It seems that zeep generates XML which is not valid according to the server.

You can see which XML is sent by enabling the debug log level, see http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/latest/transport.html#debugging

Comment: The `zeep.transports` module helped me fix it. Thank you!